# Are "Where can I buy X" questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Can we post questions like, "Where can I get X?", where "X" is something like a cushion, a singing bowl, or a statuette?

Answer (score 2):

"Shopping" questions are discouraged on Stack Exchange, partly because they attract spam, and partly because answers may become obsolete after some years.

On this site we have allowed questions about where to find teachers, groups, retreats, etc.

But perhaps we shouldn't allow questions about where to buy various things. We have already, in the past, had some spam (unsolicited commercial communication).

See also [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/139866) on the network meta for all Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like "what is the name of this Buddha or Bodhisattva or Dharma Protector?" referring to statues or pictures is OK. The intention is to identify the statue or picture.

But asking "where can I buy this statue or picture?"  is not allowed under the guidelines.